# Using an NSString and UIImageView to load image from URL, failing on some URLs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsdata, nsurl

I've got some code to load an image from a URL, it seems to work ok.  Unless the URL contains curly brackets.  This seems like it is a string formatting problem?  I can't figure it out.

ex 
@"http://site/image.png   //works

@"http://site/{image}.png //doesn't work

```
    NSString* mapURL = @"http://site.com/directory/{map}.png";
    NSLog(mapURL);
    NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mapURL]];

    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
    [imageView setImage:image];
    [imageData release];
    [image release];
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found this helpful

http://simonwoodside.com/weblog/2009/4/22/how_to_really_url_encode/